# F12 VSCode (Go To Definition) pointing to the wrong module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a scenario with a Python project that has 2 similar modules (same name and same structure).

I make sure that the PYTHONPATH has the right order of imports so that it has the behavior I expect.
But the F12  Go To Definition function within VSCode does not follow that pattern and goes to the definition in the wrong module/folder.

How can I make sure GTD follows the order in the PYTHONPATH? Or at least force it to go to the folder I want?

Comment: Possibly related settings: `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` and `python.analysis.extraPaths`.

Comment: Thank you! This with a couple of others worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference - thanks to user for the comment -  setting the below variables in my settings.json helped solve the issue:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [your_folder],
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [your_folder],
"python.analysis.include": [your_folder],
"python.analysis.exclude": [some_other_folder],
```